# ClassNotFoundException Error any ideas?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I get this error for my code:

```
C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\AIB>java GreenhouseControls -f examples1.txt
Restarting system
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ThermostatNight
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at GreenhouseControls$Restart.action(GreenhouseControls.java:139)
        at tme3.Controller.run(Controller.java:32)
        at GreenhouseControls.main(GreenhouseControls.java:197)
```

I believe I have a classpath errors.

Comment: Show us the structure and packages of your classes.

Comment: Try a full name with package name

Comment: There you go guys I added more info. Gregory Thermostatnight is in same file

Comment: Gregory is right, I think. Maybe you have to use a fully qualified name (including package) for `ThermostatNight` when creating it.

Comment: Can you execute `ThermostatNight tn = new ThermostatNight();` inside the Java file?

Comment: GreenhouseControls.java:127: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor ThermostatNight()
location: class GreenhouseControls.ThermostatNight
                ThermostatNight tn = new ThermostatNight();
                                     ^

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add your compiled java files (i.e., Event.class, ThermostatNight.class, ...) of Event.java, ThermostatNight.java to the classpath:

```
java -cp "target/*" GreenhouseControls -f examples1.txt
```

I assume that your compiled class files are in the target directory.

Comment: C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\TME3>java -cp "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/TME3/tme3/Events.class" GreenhouseControls -f examples1.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GreenhouseControls

Comment: You have to add all .class files to your classpath. Typically your IDE compiles your classes for you, if not you have to compile them using `javac`. You should place all your .class files into a folder and you can add all files to the classpath with the mentioned syntax (see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)

Comment: ThermostatNight is not in different package it exists in one file. Only Events.java is in a different file

Comment: But you only add the Event.class in your classpath... you also have to add the .class file which contains the GreenhouseControls class and the ThermostatNight class

Comment: This is what i get, once I did your trick java.lang.InstantiationException: GreenhouseControls$ThermostatNight
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:335)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
        at GreenhouseControls$Restart.action(GreenhouseControls.java:140)
        at tme3.Controller.run(Controller.java:32)
        at GreenhouseControls.main(GreenhouseControls.java:197)

Comment: Ok thats a different exception can you open a new post and show the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way.

```
java -classpath YourProjectWar.jar com.yourpackage.ClassWithMain -f examples1.txt
```